# Upgrading databases between MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, wamp, upgrade

I had installed WAMP 2.0i some time ago and have been developing sites using PHP and MySQL and all was fine. Recently, I have had to change my hard-drive and reinstall Windows 7 and my applications. This all went smoothly until I got to WAMP. I downloaded the latest version of WAMP (v 2.4 32bit) and installed both Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package x86 and WAMP 2.4 without any problems.

I then copied by site files from my backup www folder to the new installation and this was fine too.

Then I ran into problems - I now have to move my databases over to the new installation. My previous WAMP installation ran MySQL 5.0.1. My new installation runs MySQL 5.5. My databases are mainly INNODB but also with a few older MyISAM ones thrown in.

My new installation recognises that I have a MySQL 5.0 folder and provides the option in the MySQL versions but trying to change to this version stops MySQL from running.

I have tried to manually copy the files from mysql5.0.1b/data to mysql5.5.x/data with the log files, ibdata1 and .pid files as well as the wampserver.conf file. This didn't work so I uninstalled, reinstalled and then tried it all again without the log files, etc - only the database folders and this still didn't work.

I've searched for solutions and most of them revolve around exporting my databases using mysqldump or other scripts  - unfortunately I only have the files and no MySQL access to them.

I found a solution that describes how to copy the files over, change the wampserver.conf file (have to change mysqld-nt.exe to mysqld.exe) and then run mysql_upgrade tool but this generated errors primarily saying that the tables in my databases didn't exist. When I tried this I did copy over all my databases with the ibdata file.

Can anybody help me to understand the issues involved in what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,

Nadeem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically trying to upgrade from way too far back in history.

According to the `mysql` documentation you will need to upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1, once that is done you can jump from 5.1 to 5.5

[Upgrading from 5.0 to 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrading.html)

[Upgrading from 5.1 to 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html)

In your situation it would seem simpler to install a MySQL 5.0 into a WAMPServer and just run a backup of your existing databases.

Then restore them to a 5.5 mysql.

This appears to be a link to a [5.0 install for windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html)

[Here is a link to HOWTO manually install MYSQL to a WAMPServer installation](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,118264,118265#msg-118265)

I hope this helps